# not of nth child selector not working in sass

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am trying to apply certain styles to all items in list besides the first child. I think I set up the sass correctly, however the style is not being applied currently.

html

```
  <div class="list">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of data; index as i; first as isFirst; last as isLast"class="list-item">

                        <input class="radio" name="radio" type="radio" />
                        <label for="radio1">Buttom</label>
                    </div>

        </div>
```

sass

```
 .list label:not(:nth-of-type(1))::before{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this doing by all the items bg blue and the first one's bg to white or whatever your background is.

```
<div class="list">
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index"  [class.first]="i === 0">
    <input class="radio" name="radio" type="radio" />
<label for="radio1" class="lbl">{{item.name}}</label>
```

and your css should be like this:

```
label {
  background-color:blue;
}
.first label {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

I assume your data is like that:

```
 data = [
    {name: "car"},
    {name: "truck"},
    {name: "bike"}
  ]
```

[This is working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5vmgc)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean selecting all `.list-item` except the first one, the CSS will be like:

```
.list-item:not(:nth-of-type(1))::before {
    content: '';
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Since you are using pseudo element `::before`, you may want to use `content: ''` to specify some content, otherwise `background-color` will has no effect.